# Newenvironment - find the length of input

Tags: environments, lengths

I am trying to define a new environment where the input text is placed inside a minipage, which has width equal to the length of the input text (something like a variable width box).  What I would like to have additional is a horizontal line over the box which has length more than the input text (say 1.5*input-text-width), as shown below:

[image]

Though there are many methods to create a variable width box, I didn't see a way to draw a line over the box which which has its length connected to the input text. I believe that determining the length of the input text is the right way to proceed. In *newcommand*, the length can be easily determined, since the input text can be called as #1. My question is how to decide the input text length for a newenvironment. More exactly, where is the **text-body** defined inside the newenviroment?

A minimum working example is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{varlength}{
\begin{center}
\rule{0.9\textwidth}{0.8pt}

\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}}{
\end{minipage}
\end{center}}


\begin{document}
\begin{varlength}
This is a text inside fixed length minipage with over-line

I want the same to be repeated for variable width box
\end{varlength}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Look for `varwidth` in the answers to the question marked as duplicate.

Comment: @egreg, thanks for the link. But in my environment, there is a line which spans over the text and has a length equal to 1.2 times the input-text-length. That's why I was asking for a way to find input length. I could not find a way to fix it in the link you shared. Should I edit my question?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand.

Comment: @egred, I have edited my question, sorry for the delayed response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The “length of the input” doesn't make much sense, because TeX typesets paragraphs at a fixed size, using the current value of the parameter `\hsize` (normally equal to `\textwidth` in LaTeX).

You can have minipages that adapt to the size of the material inside them using `varwidth`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\newsavebox{\varlengthbox}
\newenvironment{varlength}
 {\begin{lrbox}{\varlengthbox}\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}}
 {\end{varwidth}\end{lrbox}
  \begin{center}
  \rule{1.5\wd\varlengthbox}{0.4pt}\\
  \usebox{\varlengthbox}
  \end{center}}

\begin{document}

\begin{varlength}
This is a text inside fixed length\\
minipage with over-line

I want the same to be repeated for\\
variable width box
\end{varlength}

\end{document}
```

[image]